# dbcp connection pool unstable: churning

Tags: java, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

My java application uses DBCP pooling, however under load I'm seeing some strange behaviour. The pool is configured as follows:

```
database.name.mydb=mydb
mydb.password=##248ZwTdcygYhQ4zyiogkFg\=\=
mydb.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://mydb:1433/mydb;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;appName=mydbconn1
mydb.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource

mydb.username=mydb
mydb.initialSize=100
mydb.maxActive=200
mydb.minIdle=1000
mydb.maxIdle=200        
mydb.useApacheDBPC=true
mydb.propertyStore=true
mydb.description=MyDB Live Database
```

At start-up I see the connection at 200 connections when viewed in the SQL Server database connection list. When I start the application load test this then starts to churn, never dropping below 190 that I've seen. Typical values are between 196-199 connections.

A customer has complained of a lot of connections to the database appearing in TIME_WAIT on the application server. This suggests that connections are being closed on the application side and not returned to the pool.

This may be what i'm seeing as the numbers drop and then go up again.

Question is what is causing this? Is this an application bug or some mis-configuration in the DBCP? What would cause connection churning like this?

Comment: Have you observed something strange in app or dbcp logs?

Comment: application logs are fine, what are the dbcp logs?